# How to create a tileable natural stone texture?

Tags: gimp, patterns, tiles

How can I make below natural stone wall tileable ?

[image]

Preferred solution would be to generate above wall in GIMP, but using a photo and making that tileable would also be acceptable-

Comment: What have you tried? Where is that failing? I mean.. uhmmm... you clearly read that [meta post](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/why-the-upvotes) then do the exact same thing?

Comment: @Scott you are right … Actually, I've got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I got what I wanted by following [this tutorial](https://www.hypergridbusiness.com/2012/12/how-to-create-seamless-textures/):

1. First, I deformed the original picture from the question so that it's all straight:

   [image]
2. Then, I used Filters->Map->Make seamless. This produced the following image:

   [image]

   Pretty well, right ? You can only discover some leftovers / anomalies from the original image if you put them side by side.
3. To prove it is tileable, I have copied the above image and filled a bigger one with it. That's how it looks:

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a long comment.

Try PBR generators.

Some free:

- https://www.blender.org/
- https://rodzilla.itch.io/material-maker
- https://github.com/njbrown/texturelab

Comment: What is an PBR ?

Comment: [**P**hysically **B**ased **R**endering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physically_based_rendering).